# How to include node sources in repository?

Tags: node.js, git

Is there any way to include the sources used by npm install into the project repository?

I would like to achieve that the project can be build without needing external resources, to improve performance and reliability.
With Ruby i used to cache the gems via bundler, but i can't find any such option for npm.

Not the `node_modules` folder should be included, as this does not work across node versions/platforms, but the sources used to generate the contents in the `node_modules` folder.

I found yarn seems to have an option like this: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/cache/

However npm does not seem to have anything.

Comment: `git add node_modules`?

Comment: For this to work modules should not be installed globally (no `-g` in `npm install`) and not ignored via `.gitignore`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly the opposite of what i want, in the `node_modules` folder is the compiled code, which will not work across different node versions or platforms in every case.
I want the sources to build the contents of the `node_modules` folder in the repository, not the finished code

Comment: You can create your own npm repository and put all the sources there. It may improve performance if it is all in your local network.